# Uninstalling GDAL 2.0 (Mac)

Tags: python, gdal

I installed GDAL 2.0 a while ago, but it does not seem to support GEOS for Python.  I'm looking to downgrade to GDAL 1.11 (from kyngchaos), but when I try to uninstall GDAL 2.0, it doesn't seem to fully uninstall.  So when I go to install 1.11, It still tells me that I'm running 2.0 and I get the "GEOS support not enabled". How can I uninstall GDAL 2.0 and/or downgrade to 1.11?

I apologize if I am not providing enough information, I'm doing this for a class and I'm not well-versed in this kind of thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you install GDAL 2.0?  From source, MacPorts, etc?  This will result in different installation locations.

Answer (score 0):

I battled with gdal for years until I found conda.  First, make sure you install the anaconda distribution: https://www.continuum.io/downloads.  Then just use the following command:

```
conda install gdal
```

Comment: The question concerns _uninstalling_ GDAL. (conda is really a great way to _install_ it, though.)